# HP LaserJet 4200 shows "Manual Feed Tray 1" when printing from Word

Tags: printing, printer, hp-laserjet

I have an HP LaserJet 4200 printer that is acting really weird. I can print from internet just fine, no problem... but when I try to print from a document used in Microsoft Word, for example, I always get:

> Manual Feed Tray 1

It's a networked printer and only an administrator account can make changes to it.
I have also tried:

- resetting the printer back to factory settings
- uninstalling and reinstalling on the PCs and the server it is connected to

I should also add that it is asking for "Plain Letter" in tray 1.

Comment: Does this only happen in word? I know word has special settings for a cover page, aka special paper which might not be present in the printer. WHich will cause it to ask you to insert that paper in the manual feed tray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the print driver on the print server.  A lot of times it will work with not matching print driver versions (like 4100 drivers will work on 4200) but not supporting all the features.

Comment: one word: what? (check the edit history, people)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the proper information for the tray:

- Tray 1 Size: Any
- Tray 1 Type: Any

---

- Tray 2 Size: Letter
- Tray 2 Type: Plain

---

- Tray 3 Size: Legal
- Tray 3 Type: Plain

I use the same as you do on the same network environment and that should fix it!

Comment: My setup is pretty much the same except for tray 3 I use Letter/Letterhead.

Comment: Set it as I told, this should do the trick. Also, power cycle the printer when it's done.

Answer (score 1):

The paper size configured in word and the printer/your print driver seems to differ. Whereas word has some size configured (in `normal.dot(x)`), your browser just fits the website to the given paper size.

The printer can be configured to know which kind of paper is in a paper tray (A4, letter, A5, ...). Make sure this information is equal on the printer and your computer. Printing a status/configuration page at the printer can help.

If you cannot change these settings because they're locked by the administrator contact him.

Comment: I am the administrator, the word document itself is configured to letter, standard 8.5 x 11.

Comment: So printer and driver are also configured to letter (both equally, at least one tray must be letter)?